# I want bot to send first message only

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a spam command. I want users to enter a message to spam but only the first message should be spam. No other message should be registered if 1 spam is already running.
My code -

```
else if (command === prefix + "spam" && args[0] !== undefined) {
        message.reply("Quick tip: Use `stopspam` command to stop this")
        spamInterval = setInterval(() => {
          message.channel.send(`${args.slice(0).join(" ")}`);
        }, 1500);
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Define outside an status variable

```
let spamrunning=0
```

Then add the condition of that status variable, and the change of it.

```
else if (command === prefix + "spam" && args[0] !== undefined && spamrunning==0) {
            message.reply("Quick tip: Use `stopspam` command to stop this")
            spamrunning=1
            spamInterval = setInterval(() => {
              message.channel.send(`${args.slice(0).join(" ")}`);
            }, 1500);
          }
```

and change status again when you clear the interval

```
else if (command === prefix + "stopspam") {
         ...
         spamrunning=0
}
```

Comment: I tried it, it didn't work for me

Comment: what didn't work? was there an error? could you specify something more?

Comment: There was no proper error, but when  i tried this, nothing changed, it still accepted more than 1.